# Unable to hide X-Axis in horizontal stacked chart.js

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, graph, charts, chart.js

After setting up a stacked horizontal bar chart using chartjs, the x-axis cannot be hidden. I have tried numerous ways to remove it like using "display:false" and making the text transparent but to no avail. Here is what it looks like and what I want it to look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXY47.jpg

Thanks in advance~!

Current Chartjs code:

```
datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Example Data One',
          data: [10],
          backgroundColor: '#C4D156',
          borderColor: "#ffffff",
          borderWidth: 1.5
        },
        {
          label: 'Example Two, etc',
          data: [25],
          backgroundColor: '#68A03F',
          borderColor: "#ffffff",
          borderWidth: 1.5
        },
        {
          label: 'Three',
          data: [55],
          backgroundColor: '#2F9138',
          borderColor: "#ffffff",
          borderWidth: 1.5
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
      bodySpacing: 4,
      xPadding: 12,
      mode: "nearest",
      intersect: 0,
      position: "nearest"
    },
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {stacked: true},
      ],
      xAxes: [
        {stacked: true},
        {gridLines: {
          display:false
        }
      },
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the label/text on the axis is done with that

```
options: {
  ...
  scales: {
    ...
    xAxes: [{
      ticks: {
         display: false //this will remove the label/text
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: it worked! i originally tried that but i realized i put that condition in another set of curly brackets so it didnt read it. Thank you Slavian!

Comment: @Anthony: please mark this answer as accepted if you think it was the solution to your question.